# Looking for formalization of the idea of low-variance predictors

Tags: variance, feature-selection, games

In baseball, Bill James suggested using, to predict next season's winning percentage
`runs_scored^2/(runs_scored^2 + runs_allowed^2)`, rather than this season's winning percentage, because there is a great deal of luck involved in winning games.  Similarly, I think the number of points a football (American) team may be expected to allow is better predicted with at what rate they have given up yards, rather than at what rate they have given up points, because the former is subject to less luck.
My question is how would one go about building a predictive model that would select the low variance predictors, rather than the high-variance ones, which tend to do better on the training set?  Is there anything better than just training a number of models and testing their performance on independent data?